# Thread.join times out even though delegate appears completed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm debugging an issue in someone else's .NET Framework 4.8 C# code where it tries to instantiate a type from a third party assembly using Activator.CreateTypeInstance, which is called from inside a delegate that's passed to a background STA thread. Once the thread is started, the calling thread blocks on Thread.join for max 60 seconds. Don't ask me why background threads are used here (the code is over 10 years old), as Thread.Join wipes out any concurrency benefits.

In any case, the type is instantiated and the delegate completes, but Thread.Join still waits until the 60 second timeout elapses.  In Visual Studio threads pane, when I use the debugger's "break all" after the delegate completes but before the timeout elapses, I can see that the thread is destroyed in the threads pane, yet Thread.Join is still waiting, so I'm wondering what could cause this kind of behaviour? Could it be tied to the call to Activator.CreateInstance leaving some residual state/handles open?

Comment: I feel it will be impossible for you to provide a [mcve]. If you were to try you'll solve your own problem. In other words, you need to try make a [mcve].

Comment: _"I can see that the thread is destroyed"_ Which thread do you refer to? What does destroyed mean? Since a thread has no such state, and the calling thread is still keeping the reference.

Comment: Let me guess that STA is causing a deadlock against the UI thread. Do *not* block ever if you are using STA.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Join` doesn't return until the thread has stopped executing or until the allotted time interval has passed. (See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/destroying-threads)

My guess would be that even though the delegate is completing, it isn't completing the thread, and so `Thread.Join` remains waiting until it times out.